# Swap image and call CSS to reposition elements in Bootstrap navbar

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Basic/Intermediate front-end dev here;

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(".navbar").offset().top > 100) {
        $('#small-logo').addClass('affix');
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("top-nav-collapse");
        $('.navbar-header img').attr('src', 'img/logo_sm.png');
        $('#scrollSwap').addClass('small-logo')
    } else {
        $('#large-logo').removeClass('affix');
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").removeClass("top-nav-collapse");
        $('.navbar-header img').attr('src', 'img/logo_lg.png');
        $('#scrollBack').addClass("large-logo center-block");
    }
});
```

I'm really struggling to position an image after it is swapped in my edited `bootstrap` nav, here's my hacked together `jQuery` so far.

I'm calling the class '`small-logo`', which changes the position attribute and adds some `margin-left`, but it doesn't want to move. What am I doing wrong?

CSS:

```
.small-logo {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
```

HTML element here:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
    <div class="container">
        <div><img id="scrollSwap" class="small-logo visible-xs visible-sm hidden-md" src="img/logo_sm.png" /></div>
        <div><img id="scrollBack" class="large-logo center-block hidden-sm hidden-xs" src="img/logo_lg.png" style="" /></div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="fleet.html">The Fleet</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
        <!-- <li><a href="#">Airstream Story</a></li> -->
        <li><a href="#">Corporate</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Private Hire</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Structures</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the element is absolutely positioned, try using `left: -15px` instead. Or if you want to move something left 15px, you can also just use `transform: translateX(-15px);`.